# Exemption from withholding on W-4 form for highschool student

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-w-4

My daughter (WA - USA, highschool student with green card) has 2 part-time jobs paying about $1500 each per year. I claim her as a dependent on my tax return.

She has to fill out a W-4 form for her second job. Can she claim exemption from withholding?

The [tax withholding calculator](https://apps.irs.gov/app/tax-withholding-estimator) requires info from a pay stub that she doesn't have yet.

Comment: Follow the instructions? On the 2020 form, it's paragraph 3 of the instructions. If she owed no tax in 2019 and it looks like she will owe no tax in 2020, she can mark the form exempt.

Comment: @mkennedy thanks for the response. That is what I thought, but it wasn't clear to me whether me claiming them as dependents changed any of that.